# Spread operator to update array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects. In that array, I want to update a single object, and in that object, I want to update only specific properties. I tried:

```
setRequiredFields(prevRequiredFields => ([
            ...prevRequiredFields, prevRequiredFields.find(x => x.name = field) ?  {
                isValid: isValid,
                content: content,
                isUnchanged: false
            }
]));
```

But it didn't work. Required fileds is an array with the following structure:

```
[{
    name: "Name",
    isValid: false,
    content: "",
    isUnchanged: true,
    tip: "Name cannot be empty",
    isValidCondition: notEmptyRegex,
    reportState: validateField
}]
```

What I'm trying to do here is to update only a `isValid`, `content` and `isUnchanged` of one specific object inside that array. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Why not use `.map` instead then? Just do `setRequiredFields(prevRequiredFields.map(item => item.name === field ? {...item, isValid, content, isUnchanged: false} : item)`

Comment: share reproducable example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an array of objects, and you want to update few properties of one of the objects inside the array. Then you could do something like this.

```
const index = state.findIndex(x => x.name === field);
if(index > -1) {
  const newState = [...state];
  newState[index] = { 
    ...newState[index],
    isValid: isValid,
    content: content,
    isUnchanged: false
  }
  setRequiredFields(newState);
}
```

- Find the index of the object that you want to update.
- Add properties inside that object.
- Update the react state.